# How @Autowired Work using Reflection and how invoke appropriate Setter Method

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

My Main Problem is that i can use Reflection API and i can invoke the setter method in my User bean class.But I have Only have UserBean objects. I does not know which setter method to invoke.i want extract all information in my User bean Object and the invoke appropriate Method using Reflection.

//-->This My User Bean Class

```
public class User {

 private String name;
 private int age;

private String getName() {
    return name;
}
private void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
private int getAge() {
    return age;
}
private void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

 void callMethod() { System.out.println("Name :- "+name+" Age :-"+age); }

 @Override
  public String toString() { return "User [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";}
}
```

//--->This My Main Method

```
public class TestCase {

public static Object getBean(String beanClassName) throws Exception
{
    Class klass = Class.forName(beanClassName);
    Object obj = klass.newInstance();            
    Method[] b = klass.getDeclaredMethods();

    String MethodName1 = "setName";
    String MethodName2 = "setAge";
    String name ="sanket";
    int age = 21;

    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
    {
        if(b[i].getParameterTypes().toString().equals(MethodName1))
        {
             b[i].setAccessible(true);
             b[i].invoke(obj,name); 
        }
        if(b[i].getName().equals(MethodName2))
        {
             b[i].setAccessible(true);
             b[i].invoke(obj,age);  
        }
    }


    return obj;
}

public static void main(String ars[]) throws Exception
{
    Object obj1 = getBean("www.Fouth.User");

    System.out.println(obj1.toString());
}
}
```

I my case I can invoke the setter method manually because i can invoke the setter method bases of method name.

I want Extract information in User Bean Class, and identify on the bases of value which setter to invoked.

In spring @AutoWired is does that.How they will identify which setter to invoke and inject dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring identifies which setters to inject dependencies by figuring out which setters are annotated with `@Autowired` , `@Inject` , `@Resources` etc.

Then it figures out which value to inject into the setter by checking the type of the setter arguments and injects the bean that has the same type.

If multiple beans have the same type, it then check the bean name. It will inject the bean that has the same name as configured in the injection point using `@Qaulifer` or `@Resources`.

If there are still multiple beans that satisfy to inject , `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` happens.

If there are no beans that satisfy to inject, `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` happens.

Comment: I only have Object in my userBean class. and i invoke the setter method only bases of value.

Comment: How it Possible @Ken Chan

Comment: You mean how to determine which value to inject ? see my update

Comment: Yes I want this  "Then it figures out which value to inject into the setter by checking the type of the setter arguments and injects the bean that has the same type" . I want this but internal implementation using reflection

Comment: It is very complicated ,  but at the end , it will use reflection API , but some abstraction over it such as `BeanWrapper` .You can check `AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory` as the entry point....

Comment: Please give me some link original @Autowired Source Code

Comment: already give you , it is `AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory` .Let 's explore from it